# HP ENVY 17 Overheating?

Tags: laptop, cpu, cooling, temperature

I'm using an HP ENVY 17 and am having issues with the temperature inside the computer being around 83C mean during idle on a Linux system. These temperatures are far too high for system idle, and while doing anything important or processor heavy temperatures tend towards the 93C or higher range.

Something clearly seems to be wrong, the fan is running (Although it has not been cleaned in about 2 years. (I've had the laptop for a few years now (Probably more than 4, I can't remember an exact number)) And the laptop rests on my desk all the time, not necessarily near dust, although the laptop is not inclined above the plane of the desk. The mean temperature in my room is 25C.

I have a suspicion that the thermal compound may have gone bad, but I'm not sure if this is the case. I've heard that the hp envy platforms in general always run hot, but this seems to hot for normal operation. Should I replace the thermal compound or could it be something else? How long does thermal compound typically last for?

PSensor While Watching a Youtube Video After Idling for a Long Time:
[image: PSensor]

Comment: Clean the cooling fins with canned air....https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c01657439?jumpid=reg_r1002_usen_c-001_title_r0001

Comment: Before you do anything.  Remove the dust from the machine.

Comment: I cleaned every entrance I could find with my air compressor's blow gun (Set to 60 PSI, and only in small pulses, so not to damage the fan), and it smoked like crazy due to all the dust. It looks like that solved it. Mean temperature is now 58C and whenever it heats up, it cools quickly.